# Why does my VBA Code Terminate after a .Copy method is performed on unpredictable instances?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below has been running for no problems for several months already, but for some reason, it suddenly glitched up. When I step through the code, it terminates instantly after running a `.Copy` method to copy data from a sheet to another. I do not see any reason why this should happen. Also, the destination worksheet is actually a `Very Hidden` worksheet and when I try to set it to `Visible`, it errors with something like: `Cannot set to the Visible property`. But if I change it from `Very Hidden` to `Hidden` then to `Visible`, I was able to change the worksheet to visible. I do not know if it has anything to do why the code abruptly ends, but I am guessing it might have.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Delete_Voucher()

Dim Total_rows_Entries As Long
Dim Delete_row As Variant
Dim Total_rows_Deleted As Long
Dim i As Long

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Unprotect Password:="test"

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").ListObjects("Entries").ListColumns(3).Range
Total_rows_Entries = .Find(What:="*", _
    After:=.Cells(1), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
End With

InputDelete:
Delete_row = InputBox("Input the voucher number you want to delete.")
If StrPtr(Delete_row) = 0 Then
    GoTo CancelInputDelete
ElseIf Delete_row = "" Then
    MsgBox " Cannot be blank. Please enter a voucher number to delete."
    GoTo InputDelete
ElseIf IsError(Application.Match(Val(Delete_row), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Range("A2:A" & Total_rows_Entries), 0)) = True Then
    MsgBox "No such voucher number. Please Input the correct voucher number."
    GoTo InputDelete
End If

EntriesStart:
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").ListObjects("Entries").ListColumns(3).Range
Total_rows_Entries = .Find(What:="*", _
    After:=.Cells(1), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
End With

Total_rows_Deleted = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Deleted Vouchers").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Total_rows_Entries
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Cells(i, 1) = Val(Delete_row) Then
'The code between this line is executed successfully, but then immediately ends running the program afterwards
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Deleted Vouchers").Cells(Total_rows_Deleted + 1, 1)
'The code between this line is executed successfully, but then immediately ends running the program afterwards
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Deleted Vouchers").Cells(Total_rows_Deleted + 1, 9) = Now()
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        GoTo EntriesStart
    End If
Next i

MsgBox ("Voucher number: " & Delete_row & " has been successfully deleted.")

CancelInputDelete:
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Entries").Protect _
    DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, _
    AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, _
    AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, Password:="test"
End Sub
```

Why do excel codes glitch up despite the fact that the code is unchanging? I noticed the employee had about 10 workbooks open, but I believe the code should be robust as I used `ThisWorkbook` in declaring the objects. I closed the workbook and re-opened it, but same problem occurs. However, on another computer the code works fine with no change in code.

After she closed all excel workbooks, I wanted to test whether it'll work if the whole instance of Excel was reset, the code worked fine and no traces of the problem was seen. I am confused why this would happen.

Comment: In instances where that has happened to me, it has frequently been due to some previously unaccounted for change in the data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld but despite having no changes in data, it worked fine after all instances of excel was closed. So I think it shouldn't be a wrongly encoded data point

Comment: That's true, too. So far, the only thing you have to work with is the change in the environment, possibly with the multiple books being open, but maybe something else.  Unless/until you can reproduce the error, it's going to be tough to find. Nothing jumps out at me with your code.  Maybe try posting on the Code Review group.

Comment: Hint: rewrite your logic without using `GoTo`. None of them are necessary.

Comment: @AJD You mean the `GoTo` is causing the glitch?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Yeah it's hard to reproduce this error but maybe it'll appear again next time

Comment: The `GoTo` creates spaghetti code that makes it hard to follow branches. Strongly controlled loops with clear logic will help you identify any logic/termination faults.